# FullPage.js - add active class to menu anchor when on a nonematching section

Tags: jquery, menu, fullpage.js

Okay, the title might be a bit hard to understand, I'll try and explain.

So I'm using [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/)

I have in total 9 sections:
Home
About(about has 6 "undersections" that is a continuation of the first about section)
Contact

In the menu there are only 3 navigation options Home, about, contact. I've made the menu so that the active class is added when on corresponding section - as simply done with ready made options.
When I scroll and leave the first about section the active class is remove and the menu item is not highlighted.
So here's the thing I want the active class to remain on all the "undersections" of about. So the menu item "About" is highlighted until the contact section.

I thought I'd make it work with some "outside" JS so depending on the url the class would be added to the anchor with id "all-about":

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            if (location.href.match(/#about1/ig) || location.href.match(/#about2/ig)){
                $('#all-about').addClass('active');
            }
        });
```

This does not work.
What in the fullpage JS would I change or how to change my code to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make use of the plugin callbacks to achieve that.

You could make use of `afterLoad` with something like this:

```
$.fn.fullpage({
    slidesColor: ['red', 'blue'],
    afterLoad: function(anchor, index){
        var activeItem;

        if(index == 1 || index == 2 || index == 3){
            activeItem = $('#menu').find('li').first()
        }else{
             activeItem = $('#menu').find('li').last()    
        }

        activeItem
            .addClass('active')
            .siblings().removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Note that  I'm not using the `menu` option anymore to handle the active class as I wish.

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/6/)

Comment: Thanks, made some modifications, targeted id's instead of li first/last so it would work properly with my layout. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This is old but for anyone else that comes along.. this feature is built in to Fullpage.js. Just change "lockAnchors: false," to "lockAnchors: true," in your fullpage.js defaults, or as an option when you call it up. Then you need to add your css for the #menu li.active that is created. Done.